# Overflow on a resizing and centred background image?

Tags: css

On the first page/header of a one page site I'm having a portrait of a person with the arms stretched out to the sides. This portrait is centred and pulled down to the bottom of this first page/header. All works fine but when I resize the window to the size of a mobile device the portrait gets too small, because the 'background-size: cover' value makes it resize.

Is there a way to make the portrait get smaller till to a certain window width and from then on overflow into the off while staying centred? 'min-width' makes it overflow only to the right of the window without being centred anymore.

I want it to overflow because on mobile devices the stretched out arms don't have to be visible, but the rest of the portrait should be visible. And the image should keep a height of about 70% of the window height.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="cont-pic">
        <div id="pic">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}

#cont-pic {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#pic {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url('img/pic.png') no-repeat center bottom;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8QbXe/). Just imagine that the wings are the stretched out arms which don't have to be visible on mobile devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do it with media queries if you know the minimum width that you want. Then you can set a fixed size.

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
  #pic {
    background-size:350px 100%;
  }
}
```

Check it here the code http://jsfiddle.net/8QbXe/15/ ,all you have to do is change the real dimensions you want.

Comment: Didn't look close enough the first time. This seems to be almost the thing I want. Thanks a lot!!!